# File deletion bypassing trash on OS Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, trash

Deleting files in finder is now permanently deleting the files (i.e. basically doing  *rm filename*) and is not moving the items to trash. How do I fix this behavior? I like being able to undo my deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Check what the permissions and owner for `~/.Trash/` are:

```
$ ls -led ~/.Trash
drwxr-xr-x  39 lauri  staff  1326 Apr 17 02:49 /Users/lauri/.Trash
```

If the owner is `root`, run `sudo chown $USER ~/.Trash`. If the permissions are for example `dr-xr-xr-x` instead of `drwxr-xr-x`, run `chmod 755 ~/.Trash`.

Comment: The permissions were all right, so this didn't actually solve my question. It turns out that in the end, a good old "windows solution" reboot was all that was needed. Nevertheless, thank you for the heads up. I didn't think to check the permissions.